# How to install GNU build tools from Blastwave

Tags: solaris, gnu

I am trying to install the GNU build tools on Solaris using Blastwave. I have installed CSWgcc4 but when I run gcc or gcc4 I get command not found. There is not any file like gcc gcc4 in /opt/csw/bin.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to `/opt/csw/gcc4/bin/gcc`